# Netbeans Chrome - clear browsing data

Tags: html, css

I'm using Netbeans to develop an HTML / CSS / Javascript / PHP app. I find that when I make HTML changes, I need to 'clear browsing data' in Chrome before the changes show. I suspect it's actually the 'cached images and files' that need to be cleared rather than the browsing history. Can someone explain why is this? And is there a way to auto clear history when launching the browser from Netbeans? It gets a little tedious when testing the app to have to clear browsing history all the time.

Comment: Ctrl + F5 (if on Windows), option-shift-r if on Mac == hard refresh. Should do it.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Cmd... Not Option...

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>) + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to make a hard refresh. If needed, you can do this:

1. Open the Dev Tools.
2. Click and Hold the Reload Button.
3. Click on the third option.

[image: preview]

**Note:** You can use Incognito Window, which doesn't cache much often.

Comment: I am using Windows

Comment: @dru37 So what?

Comment: Then just do `Ctrl`+`F5` for hard-refresh. No need to use `shift` or `r` on Windows.